# Converting HashMap into ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I have a HashMap of the following type

```
Map<MyTeacherModel, ArrayList<StudentModel>> stdByTeacher= new HashMap<>();
```

I want to convert this hash map in ArrayList in such a way that every Teacher has some number of Students.  Something like below

**--Teacher A**
   ----Std A1
   ----Std A2
   ----Std A3
   ----Std A4

**--Teacher B**
   ----Std B1
   ----Std B2
   ----Std B3
   ----Std B4

My HapMap is something like that and I just want hashmap to be transformed into an upper given array list.

**Note: I do not want to use Java 8**

I want a list of Model i.e MyModel that must contain MyTeacherModel
and ArrayList of Student model.  I want to get this list from the
HashMap I mentioned above. becuase the values inside hashmap are
similar like this.

Comment: You question is not clear, do you want a list of list?

Comment: let me update my question

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:**

```
List<MyModel> transformed= new ArrayList<>();// I assume StudentModel and MyTeacherModel are subclasses of MyModel

for(Map.Entry<MyTeacherModel, List<StudentModel>> entry : stdByTeacher.entrySet()) {
   transformed.add(entry.getKey());
   transformed.addAll(entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: read my updated question

Comment: @A.s.ALI read updataed answer :) Hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

So do you want this?

```
List<Teacher> mList = new ArrayList<Teacher>();
for (Map.Entry< MyTeacherModel, StudentModel > entry : stdByTeacher.entrySet())
{
    mList.add(new Teacher(stdByTeacher.getKey().getName(), stdByTeacher.entrySet().size());
}
```

Comment: No this is not what I want

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement :

> Student class:

```
public class Student {

    private int id;
    private String Name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

}
```

> Teacher Class:

```
public class Teacher {

    private int id;
    private String Name;
    private List<Student> students;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }
    public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Teacher other = (Teacher) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

> According to Student and Teacher model:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Teacher, List<Student>> map = new HashMap<>();

        List<Teacher> teachers = getTeachers(map);
    }

    static List<Teacher> getTeachers(Map<Teacher, List<Student>> map) {
        for (Map.Entry<Teacher, List<Student>> teacherEntry : map.entrySet()) {
            teacherEntry.getKey().getStudents().addAll(teacherEntry.getValue());
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
    }

}
```

Comment: I do not have set. But arraylist instead 

Set<Student>> map

Comment: convert set to list. i updated the same on code.

Comment: read my updated question

Comment: is there anything wrong with sudent or teacher model?